# Are there any credible shared hosting services that are compatible with subsonic projects?

Tags: subsonic, hosting

I have a website project that was written with subsonic though medium trust hosting services like GoDaddy and AT&T don't support subsonic projects.

I was wondering if anyone knows of any hosting services that will work with subsonic. I am not as tech savvy so I am looking for a tech support heavy hosting service that will be able to walk me through the hosting (live person over the phone and not a chat box).

Answer (score 1):

I used to use Subsonic 2.x with a website site with medium trust hosting (WebCentral in Australia) and didn't have any issues from a website point of view.

The database connection appeared to require the ability to read the sysobjects table which is not always standard.
Also we generated our SubSonic classes before deploying so they weren't created on the fly.

Not sure this is an answer but would be interested to know what errors you get when you try to deploy the site on GoDaddy or AT&T.

Comment: I agree. The medium trust problem is only for websites that use the build provider. No problems should occur if the code is generated in a class library beforehand.